# I have image stored in different server and i want to show that image in my website using php

Tags: php

I have image stored in different server. Now I want to show that images in website hosted in different server.

```
file_get_contents("www.example.com/img.jpeg")
```

display that image but I added a code like

```
file_get_contents("www.example.com/img2.jpeg")
file_get_contents("www.example.com/img.jpeg").
```

It doesn't show the below images. It only show the first image.

Comment: Why not `<img src="http://www.example.com/img2.jpeg">`?

Comment: Thanks for your response and  <img src="http://www.example.com/img2.jpeg">  display the image as I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function that returns the image you want as data URIs encoded with base64.

**PHP**

```
function getDataURI($path) {
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
return $base64;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="<?php echo getDataURI('http://domain.com/images/image.jpg');?>" />
```

Comment: Note that this will involve more bandwidth - base64_encode adds about 1/3, and won't be cached between pageviews.

Comment: @ceejayoz indeed you are write. This is an example function. Don't use this for large images. Usually to serve an icon (not even two!! A logo for example), where the icon size is not even more than 3kb. Also more bandwidth (not so much if used for 1-2 small images), but less requests to the server.